# How to cache a layer after it is scaled

Tags: kineticjs

I have the problem that a layer looks 'ugly' after the layer is scaled.

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
  container: "canvas", width: 500, height: 200,
});

var myLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
myLayer.x(0); 
myLayer.y(0);
myLayer.width(300);
myLayer.height(200);
myLayer.clearBeforeDraw(true);

var simpleText = new Kinetic.Text({
  x: 2,
  y: 10,
  text: 'Text',
  fontSize: 30,
  fontFamily: 'Calibri',
  fill: 'green'
});
simpleText.cache();
myLayer.add(simpleText);

stage.add(myLayer)
stage.scaleX(4);
stage.scaleY(4);
stage.draw();
```

It looks like kinetic first draws the layer, then caches it, and at last scales the layer.

Can someone help me determine how to cache a scaled layer?

Answer (score 0):

When you do simpleText.cache you are creating an image of the text.

When you scale that image (any image) 4x you will always have distortions.

To avoid distortion, use a larger font in simpleText instead of scaling.

Comment: Hi, thanks für yout quick answer but this is just an example. My oroginal code is very complex and the Problem is not the text, it's the whole stage/layer that I have to zoom

Comment: Understood!  Scaling a KineticJS layer-image 4x will always produce distortion :-(

Comment: Hi, I saw that this is now classified as a bug